# Trouble preloading CKEditor with Database Content

Tags: php, codeigniter, youtube, ckeditor, embed

I'm building an article publishing and management tool within my site's CMS and I allow users to submit Youtube embed codes through my large CKEditor text-area. This copy + embed code is stored fine in my database on submit.

The problem is, when I enter an article in an `edit` mode, it appears CKEditor is stripping the Youtube embed code from my injected copy. What can I do to stop it from doing this?

Edit: I'm using version 4.4.7, and I should add that adding

```
config.allowedContent = true;
```

to my config.js file is not solving the problem.

Comment: We would need to see a working sample on which it happens and that HTML which is stripped. Otherwise we can only guess what's happening.

Comment: It's just article copy with Youtube embeds, like this: <iframe width="853" height="480" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ePoP687mGzI?rel=0&amp;controls=0&amp;showinfo=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

The problem is, when it's injected back into CKEditor, all of that iframe code is being stripped away.

Comment: I've just checked this code on http://ckeditor.com/demo and it works fine there. That's why I asked for a sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by simply changing my CKEditor install to the Full Package instead of what I was using, Standard. Not sure why I was unable to edit the allowed content in the Standard Package though.